# Getting wrong predictions on a model loaded in java vs python using the tensorflow "saved model" api

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to load a model in Java that was trained in python and saved using the saved model api (`from tensorflow.python.saved_model`).

I'm able to load it in a separate Python script and from Java but the predictions are wrong in the Java version.

I wrote a quick example project with a simple model that demonstrates the "bug" (I'm hoping my misunderstanding).

**Python: OrTraining.py**

Save model after training using Saved Model Api.

```
builders = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
builders.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["or"], signature_def_map={
    "predict": tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def(
        inputs= {"images": x_placeholder},
        outputs= {"scores": hypothesis_function})
    })
builders.save()
```

https://github.com/JsFlo/DebuggingSavedModelJava/blob/master/OrTraining.py

**Python: OrLoadSavedModel.py**

Load model in a separate script using the Saved Model Api.

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["or"], "orTrainingModels")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
print(graph.get_operations())
x_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("or_inputs:0")
hypothesis_function = graph.get_tensor_by_name("hypothesis_output:0")
# sess.run("init")
print(sess.run(hypothesis_function, feed_dict={x_placeholder: np.array([
    np.array([1, 0]),
    np.array([0, 1]),
    np.array([0, 0]),
    np.array([1, 1]),
])}))
```

https://github.com/JsFlo/DebuggingSavedModelJava/blob/master/OrLoadSavedModel.py

**Java: OrLoadSavedModel.java**

Load

```
 SavedModelBundle savedModelBundle = SavedModelBundle.load("./orTrainingModels", "or");
 Session session = savedModelBundle.session();
```

Run

```
Tensor result = session.runner()
            .feed("or_inputs", tensorInput)
            .fetch("hypothesis_output")
            .run().get(0);
```

https://github.com/JsFlo/DebuggingSavedModelJava/blob/master/src/main/java/OrLoadSavedModel.java

Both the java version and the python version load and run the graphs without a problem but the java version doens't output the correct predictions.

At first I thought it was because the weights/bias weren't being loaded but I'm able to "run" the weights/bias operation in the java version and see that it has the correct weights that I see in the python script after training.

Check weights in java (https://github.com/JsFlo/DebuggingSavedModelJava)

```
Tensor result = session.runner()
            .fetch("da_weights")
            .run().get(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out an to be an issue with the way I was feeding the data in. Tensorflow doesn't like to create Tensors of `Boxed Types` (Integer vs int/ Float vs float) and there are checks to see if you're trying to pass in boxed types but it seems like the checks aren't that comprehensive.

*Test from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/TensorTest.java *

```
@Test
public void testCreateFromArrayOfBoxed() {
    Integer[] vector = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    try (Tensor<Integer> t = Tensor.create(vector, Integer.class)) {
        fail("Tensor.create() should fail because it was given an array of boxed values"); 
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     // The expected exception
   }
}
```

Here's an example of my issue:

```
    Float[] input = new Float[]{0f, 1f};
    Tensor tensorOutput = Tensor.create(input);
    float[] floatOutput= new float[2];
    tensorOutput.copyTo(floatOutput);
    println(Arrays.toString(floatOutput)); // -7.377E30, -7.377E30


    float[] input = new float[]{0f, 1f};
    Tensor tensorOutput = Tensor.create(input);

    float[] floatOutput= new float[2];
    tensorOutput.copyTo(floatOutput);
    println(Arrays.toString(floatOutput)); // 0, 1
```